# Error Propogation in Statistics and Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

In the domain of probability and statistics, I have often heard the following claim being made:

- When a regression model is used for an individual prediction, the prediction interval will necessarily be too large to be considered useful. Therefore, regression models tend to be better suited for inference problems (e.g. measure the effect/contribution of a variable within a regression model) compared to prediction problems (e.g. what is the predicted response for this new individual)

I have heard that this is because of "error propogation of regression models". Supposedly, when calculating the prediction error of a regression model, this will tend to involve evaluating several error terms together that will result in very large prediction intervals.

I am not quite sure that I understand this point. Can someone please comment on why "prediction intervals in regression models tend to be too large for practical purposes"? Is there any mathematical basis to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Observe iid $X_1,...,X_n \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. A 95% confidence interval for $\mu$ is
$$
\Big[\bar X - \sigma 1.96  \Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)^{1/2},
\bar X + \sigma 1.96  \Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)^{1/2}\Big].
$$
This means that we can estimate $\mu$ and control the uncertainty with precision $\sigma n^{-1/2}$.

Now if you are yet to observe $X_{n+1}$ and would like to construct from $X_1,...,X_n$ a confidence interval $\hat I$ such that $P(X_{n+1}\in \hat I) = 0.95$, you can observe that $\bar X -X_{n+1} \sim N(0, \sigma^2(1+1/n)$ and use
$$
\hat I = \Big[ \bar X -1.96\sigma\Big(1+\frac1n\Big)^{1/2}\bar X +1.96\sigma\Big(1+\frac1n\Big)^{1/2}\Big]
$$
and now the length of the prediction interval is of order $\sigma$. That's much larger than the order $\sigma/\sqrt n$ that we have for $\mu$.